# Why do two floating point multiplies give a different answer than one?

Tags: c, floating-point

I recently ran into an issue where I wasn't getting the numerical result I expected. I tracked it down to the problem that is illustrated by the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  double sample = .5;
  int a = (int)(sample * (1 << 31));
  int b = (int)(sample * (1 << 23) * (1 << 8));
  printf("a = %#08x, b = %#08x\n", a, b);
}
// Output is: a = 0xc0000000, b = 0x40000000
```

Why is the result of multiplying by (1 << 31) different than the result of multiplying by (1 << 23) * (1 << 8)? I expected the two to give the same answer but they don't.

I should note that all my floating point values are in the range [-1, 1).

Comment: Your code and question is different.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question to match the code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are apparently expecting identical results since you assume that to multiply by `(1 << 31)` is the same as to multiply by `(1 << 23)` and then by `(1 << 8)`. In general case they are not the same. You are performing the `(1 << 31)` calculation in a `signed int` domain. If your platform uses 32-bit ints, the `(1 << 31)` expression *overflows*, while both `(1 << 23)` and `(1 << 8)` are not overflowing. This immediately means that the result of the first multiplication is unpredictable.

In other words, it doesn't make any sense to do `(1 << 31)` on a platform that has only 31 bits in the value representation of `int` type. You need at least 32 value-forming bits to meaningfully calculate `(1 << 31)`.

If you want your `(1 << 31)` to make sense, calculate in it the *unsigned* domain: `(1u << 31)`, `(1u << 23)` and `(1u << 8)`. That should give you consistent results. Alternatively, you can use a larger signed integer type.